# Exception has occurred: OperationalError could not translate host name "db" to address: Unknown host

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am running locally this script. On postgres connection, I am facing "Exception has occurred: OperationalError
could not translate host name "db" to address: Unknown host". Database is up, I started it with

```
docker run --publish 8000:8000 --detach --name db REMOTEURL:latest
```

When I do the same using docker-compose, and exec to django app and run it as management command, it works. The code:

```
conn_string = "host='db' dbname='taras' user='postgres' password='postgres'"
with psycopg2.connect(conn_string) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    ... my stuff
```

I dont know why when accessing docker container from local script on my computer, docker name (url) is never recognized. Tried "localhost" instead of "db" also. When running python script inside docker container, it has no problem to recognize other docker container (db in my case). What am I missing?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I am running only database in docker. Python script is started locally, using in my windows command line

```
python myscript.py
```

Docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    image: REMOTEURL:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happens because when you launch containers, they can resolve hostnames based the names you give them internally, but if you wanna access a container from the outside (I'm assuming you wanna access your postgres db), you also need to open the port for the postgres container by adding `-p 5432:5432` to your postgres container. If you want to access postgres from another container on the same network, connect with `db:5432`, and from the outside with `localhost:5432`

Edit:
Try this as your `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    image: REMOTEURL:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. There is already --publish 8000:8000 (which is equivalent to -p)in the code I posted. Tried 5432:5432, no difference :(

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstood your question then, could you try to describe it again?

Comment: Could I see your docker compose file?

Comment: Try making the docker-compose.yml to the edit from the answer

Comment: Also may I ask what image `REMOTEURL:latest` is?

Comment: It looks like adding 

    ports:
      - 5432:5432

to by docker-compose has solved the problem. I had to change "db" to "localhost" in python file. Thank you!